# Can't use gamecenter functionality

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, game-center-leaderboard

whenever i import GameKit into my spritekit project, the game runs properly, but this show up in the console. I can't figure out how to fix this

```
    Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2015-11-03 19:44:06.672 dodge setup[89843:923765] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fe8ad032b20 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
2015-11-03 19:44:06.673 dodge setup[89843:923765] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2015-11-03 19:44:06.673 dodge setup[89843:923765] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fe8ad032b20 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
2015-11-03 19:44:06.674 dodge setup[89843:923765] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2015-11-03 19:44:06.674 dodge setup[89843:923765] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fe8ad032b20 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
2015-11-03 19:44:06.674 dodge setup[89843:923765] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2015-11-03 19:44:06.675 dodge setup[89843:923765] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fe8ad032b20 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
2015-11-03 19:44:06.675 dodge setup[89843:923765] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2015-11-03 19:44:06.675 dodge setup[89843:923765] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fe8ad032b20 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reported this as a bug, and it has been marked as a duplicate.

But I think you shall report it as well. I think that will raise the priority of the bug.